# My take on a cryptic crossword clues puzzle

Tags: cryptic-clues

Saw a few of these before, so thought I'd try my hand at making one.

> 1. Prohibited from making the US national bird unwell (7)
> 2. Recreate the fifth policeman, if we order them alphabetically (4)
> 3. Foot protection that makes your pets go away (4)
> 4. Less important attachment that adds to your lifetime indicator (9)

The answers to each clue taken together point to a final word of length (7).

Comment: I've got 1. and 3., though I'm not sure on the spelling of 3.

Comment: One of these days scientists will explain how a perfectly good puzzle can garner only a third of the ^votes of its perfectly good solution.

Comment: @humn I think I got a fair few downvotes because of the perceived issues of unclued reordering and a plural/singular mismatch in one of the clues.

Comment: It's a worldwide natural phenomenon (no downvotes here).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Prohibited from making the US national bird unwell (7)

> ILLEGAL [homophone of 'Ill Eagle']

Recreate the fifth policeman, if we order them alphabetically (4)

> COPY [E (fifth letter) + COP (policeman) alphabetically = "Cop, E" = Copy]

Foot protection that makes your pets go away (4)

> SHOE/SHOO [homophones, but no indicator as to which is the def]

Less important attachment that adds to your lifetime indicator (9)

> APPENDAGE [APPEND (adds) + AGE (lifetime indicator)]

The answers to each clue taken together point to a final word of length (7)

> Illegal copy shoe appendage = BOOTLEG [BOOT (shoe) + LEG (appendage)]

Comment: Not sure if these are acceptable cryptic clues. Three of them rely on homophones without signifying this.

Comment: Plus, there's unclued reordering in clue 1 and plural/singular mismatch in clue 4.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen other similar puzzles before where the word described by the clue is a homophone but there was no indication of such, but I may be misremembering and my apologies if that isn't an acceptable way of doing it. Not sure what you mean by unclued reordering and plural/singular mismatch. This answer is correct, though.

Comment: @JohnClifford The unclued reordering refers to the fact that the clue's order suggests 'eagle ill' rather than 'ill eagle', and there is nothing to suggest we should change their order. And 'adds' suggests 'appends', not 'append'. Generally, cryptic clues are completely literal: verb tenses, plurality match, and word orderings in the answers exactly match those in the clue, unless additional clue words suggest otherwise.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's useful information and I'll definitely keep that in mind next time I post a puzzle. Once again I'm sorry for the errors, thanks for your input!